# Python + Numpy : TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the optimal smoothing parameter for additive smoothing with 10-fold cross validation. I wrote the following code:

```
alphas = list(np.arange(0.0001, 1.5000, 0.0001))

#empty list that stores cv scores
cv_scores = []

#perform k fold cross validation
for alpha in alphas:
    naive_bayes = MultinomialNB(alpha=alpha)
    scores = cross_val_score(naive_bayes, x_train_counts, y_train, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
    cv_scores.append(scores.mean())

#changing to misclassification error
MSE = [1 - x for x in cv_scores]  

#determining best alpha
optimal_alpha = alphas[MSE.index(min(MSE))]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-9d171ddceb31> in <module>()
     18 
     19 #determining best alpha
---> 20 optimal_alpha = alphas[MSE.index(min(MSE))]
     21 print('\nThe optimal value of alpha is %f' % optimal_alpha)
     22 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I have run the same code for different values of parameters of arange() and K (cross validation). This is the first time I encountered this error. Why?

Comment: I don't see why you'd run into this - it appears min is a reference to an integer. Did you set min equal to something elsewhere in your ipython workflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere else in your code you have something that looks like this:

```
 min = 10
```

Then you write this:

```
optimal_alpha = alphas[MSE.index(min(MSE))]
```

So, `min()` is interpreted as a function call.

Comment: Completely correct, except index is function of the list, so you don't have a namespace collision. It would have to be min.

Comment: You guys are absolutely right. I recently added a new piece of code in my notebook in which I added a line 'min=999'. Thanks to both of you.